# Send byte array from c# to angular through websocket

Tags: c#, angular, binary

Hi I would like to implement a function that a byte array is sent from C# to my Angular 7 through websocket. Basically, I have a websocket running with C# and my frontend is written in Angular7.

**Please note,** the following example is a simplified one. In my real application, the object I am going to send includes about 400 fields. After serialise the object to json string, it is about 6kb. In addition, I need to send 30 such objects in about one second. Sending binary data will significantly reduce the package size and speed it up.

In C#, I have such example code to generate the payload of the websocket:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}

Test[] tests = new Test[]
{
    new Test
    {
         Id = 0,
         Value = 1.12f,
         Description = "The First Test"
    }
};


    byte[] testsByteArray;
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(m))
        {
            foreach (Test test in tests)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(test.Id);
                binaryWriter.Write(test.Value);
                binaryWriter.Write(test.Description);
            }
        }
    testsByteArray = m.ToArray();
}

Payload payload = new Payload
{
    Obj = testsByteArray
};

string a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
```

Eventually I got `a` as `{"Obj":"AAAAAClcjz8OVGhlIEZpcnN0IFRlc3Q="}` I guess the value of `Obj` is base64 encoded value of `testsByteArray`.

Now, in my frontend, I can receive the json string. The question is how to convert `AAAAAClcjz8OVGhlIEZpcnN0IFRlc3Q=` back to an object with the same format as `Test` in Angular.

What I tried:

I tried to use the following function `atob()` to decode the base64, and then use the following function to convert the decoded string to byte array

```
str2ab(str): ArrayBuffer {
    var buf: ArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Then I try to use the following code to get the values

```
let dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
console.log(dataView.getInt32(0));  // = 0
console.log(dataView.getInt32(2));  // = 0
console.log(dataView.getInt32(4));  // = 0
console.log(dataView.getInt32(6));  // = 10496
```

I am not exactly sure how to convert to correct value. Can anyone help out.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the full c# logic you've implemented?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't just send a binary blob over the network and expect a different programming language to be able to do something with it.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You are sending `JSON` to the Angular app. In Angular you want to convert it to a `byte[]`?

Comment: see b64 decode on your output, you get what you send only it's B64 encoded

Comment: the problem is you are writing binary data .. that you will need to handle yourself to get the correct values https://www.npmjs.com/package/bit-converter. I think you can find a better way to solve your problem. Why not simply serialize tests ? so you dont have a need to extract by hand the written values ..

```
Payload payload = new Payload
{
    Obj = tests
};

string a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. The reason I am doing this is that Test is just an example. In my real application, the object I am going to send is a very big one. It includes about 375 double values and some other fields. After serialize it into Json string, it is about 6kb. I need to send about 30 such object every second though the websocket. It is very slow. So I am thinking of sending binary through websocket to make the package smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Sending binary data between different platforms and languages is fragile and difficult to get right. I'd suggest converting to a platform agnostic representation (such as a JSON array) before sending, and convert back on the other side.

For example,

```
string a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tests);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rodney, I actually need to send a 6kb object every 33 millisecond. Just serialise the object to string is very slow since it is too big. That's why I am thinking of sending binary data.